# Can I follow someone on Tumblr without seeing their posts on the dashboard?

Tags: tumblr

Recently, I gave Tumblr another try and started to somewhat liking it. Some of my friends who are already on Tumblr followed by Tumblr and as a nice gesture, I followed them back.

But, unfortunately, I don't really like what they are sharing. Most of them are rather emotional and I use social networks to cheer myself up. Not get depressed. But I don't want to unfollow them either.

So, is it possible to prevent their posts from appearing in the dash board but still follow them at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Chrome extension named Tumblr Savior](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oefddkjnflmjbclpnnoegglmmdfkidip/) that helps you "blacklist" the users' posts on Tumblr.

It lets you whitelist and blacklist posts with a word of your liking (or disliking, whichever you prefer). So, add the person's Tumblr handle in the list of blacklisted words and the post won't show up fully in the dashboard. You can at any time remove the blacklist if you wish to see their posts in your dashboard.

There is also a [Firefox extension for Tumblr Savior](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tumblr-savior/).

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays you can filter content directly through Tumblr. If you add their username as a filtered term, it will filter posts coming from that blog.